# Cannot create foreign key to different database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, composite-primary-key

I have two tables on different databases in mysql. I'm trying to create a composite foreign key from one table to the other and for some reason it doesn't work. **It only works if I use a single primary key field instead of a composite key**.

The problematic constraint in the example below is `fk_dummy_table11`. I get `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint` when executing the statement.

Create table statement for "dummy" in DB NREAP:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NREAP`.`dummy` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `table1_TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  `table1_RFI_NUM_DOC` INT NOT NULL,
  `table1_RFI_VER_DOC` INT NOT NULL,
  `table1_RFI_NOM_FIC` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_dummy_table11_idx` (`table1_TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` ASC, `table1_RFI_NUM_DOC` ASC, `table1_RFI_VER_DOC` ASC, `table1_RFI_NOM_FIC` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dummy_table11`
    FOREIGN KEY (`table1_TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` , `table1_RFI_NUM_DOC` , `table1_RFI_VER_DOC` , `table1_RFI_NOM_FIC`)
    REFERENCES `TRANS`.`table1` (`TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` , `RFI_NUM_DOC` , `RFI_VER_DOC` , `RFI_NOM_FIC`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Create table statement for "table1" in DB TRANS:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TRANS`.`table1` (
  `TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  `RFI_NUM_DOC` INT NOT NULL,
  `RFI_VER_DOC` INT NOT NULL,
  `RFI_NOM_FIC` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `RFI_LOC_FIC` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `RFI_DES_FIC` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `RFI_TIPO` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `DAT_ALT` DATE NOT NULL,
  `COD_UTI_ALT` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  `DFI_VER_DOC` INT NULL,
  `DFI_NUM_SEQ` INT NULL,
  `CAM_ANO_INI_CAM` VARCHAR(4) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TDO_COD_TIP_DOC`, `RFI_NUM_DOC`, `RFI_VER_DOC`, `RFI_NOM_FIC`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Please help, this is so frustrating...

**Edit1** - I'm running mysql version 5.7.12

**Edit2** - I've ran the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command, it gives me the following output:

I'm running mysql version 5.7.12, it's the latest one I think.

I've ran innodb status:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2016-07-13 10:28:34 0x124c Error in foreign key constraint of table nreap/dummy:

        FOREIGN KEY (`table1_TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` , `table1_RFI_NUM_DOC` , `table1_RFI_VER_DOC` , `table1_RFI_NOM_FIC`)
        REFERENCES `TRANS`.`table1` (`TDO_COD_TIP_DOC` , `RFI_NUM_DOC` , `RFI_VER_DOC` , `RFI_NOM_FIC`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.
```

Comment: I just got that to work. Exactly as you have it. Mysql Version 5.6.24. Workbench version 6.3 ... http://i.imgur.com/nLkTBEW.jpg ... so maybe it is your version. idk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference a composite primary key with a foreign key using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891456/how-do-i-reference-a-composite-primary-key-with-a-foreign-key-using-mysql)

Comment: If you have PROCESS privilege you may see exact error message after failed creating foreign key with command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: Just to be sure; have you tried creating `table1` before `dummy` (or it's FK)?

Comment: I'm running mysql version 5.7.12, it's the latest one I think.

Comment: I've added more details in the OP. I'll try to debug to see if it's a version issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually figured out the problem.

I've narrowed it down to a problem in using VARCHAR keys, the restraint worked fine with other datatypes. After a few experiments I've added a specific charset for each schema and it worked. Adding the specific charset to each table also works.

Thanks for the help!